# Can I do some initial work in ReactDOM.render callback?

Tags: reactjs

I find `ReactDOM.render` have a `callback` params.

```
ReactDOM.render(element, container, [callback]);
```

So, my idea is that maybe I can do some initial work in it.

it can be:

**dispatch global action to fetch data from server to initialize my global 
state.**

My question is I want to let my component render as soon as possible.

After the static content were rendered, I will do some `ajax` operator to fetch the data.

Is that work? or, what can i do with this `callback` params?

here is my case:

for now, `src/index.js`

```
//some initial work
//sync and async work.
//...

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

My idea is to change `src/index.js` like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'), () => {
    //some initial work
    //sync work will block the html parse and render.
    //my idea is let react component render as soon as possible
})
```

I don't know my idea is correct or not. Thanks for your reply.

**Edit**

The initial work means not just `ajax`, could be `cordova` or something that `native client` provide.

Comment: Fetch shouldn't be blocking. Maybe you're doing some heavy processing which blocks, but that could be done in a worker.

Comment: Fetch data in the componentDidMount() method.

Comment: @c0deNinja yeah, I can do that. but i want to know what can i do with `react-dom render callback`?

Comment: Your question is not clear... what do you want to do in the callback?  The callback is executed after the component has rendered, so nothing is blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use the `render()` method callback for the task you are trying to use it for.
In fact, as far as I know this callback is not meant for issuing a request for initialization ; indeed, you won't have access to the components in the callback, whereas you may need to set some state when the initialization is
done...

*edited part following comments*: my personal view on ReactDOM render callback is that it is mostly useful for integrating React with another library/framework, that is not aware of React. Like: you need to execute an action when a component is rendered, as soon as it becomes available in the DOM tree; once the render callback is called, you are sure the component has been rendered to the DOM.

In your case, I would rather create a **root component** and delegate AJAX calls to it. I would render an `App` component, which renders in turn all other components. In this `App` component, I would make the initialization in `componentDidMount`.

Another option is to create **container components**, ie. a component with logic that 'wrap' simpler components. Then, implement `componentDidMount` just like with the previous solution.

Some inspiration: [React AJAX best practices](http://andrewhfarmer.com/react-ajax-best-practices/)

Comment: What is the render callback good for, then?  What types of actions might be useful there?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know what your said. The root container component `<App />`. yeah, recently, I will try to move my initial work from `index.js` to `<App/>` `componentDidMount`. I will take a look of `timeline` of `chrome` to find something.

Comment: But, I still want to know when and which case should to use `react-dom` `render` `callback`. same as @jmargolisvt.

Comment: I edited my answer to try to better answer your question.